# Generics with type constraints based on static members

Tags: c#, generics, interface, static, generic-constraints

I'm trying to use generics with constraints that don't appear to be supported, and I'm wondering if there is a clean work-around.

The problem with my initial attempt hinges on the fact that you cannot have static members in interfaces, and therefore, you cannot use interfaces to constrain types in generic declarations based on static members.

Consider this example:

Suppose you are working in a generic context, but you want to be sure that instances of `T` are able to serialize themselves to a stream (could be a file, a list of bytes), and that instances of `T` can be deserialized from a stream.

In the case of writing, this is easy, because it can be assumed that you already have an instance to work with (though you will be unable to serialize `null`):

```
public interface IStreamWritable
{
    // When called, this IStreamWritable instance
    // serializes itself to a stream.
    void Write(IStream stream);
}

...

void Write<T>(IStream stream, T t) where T : IStreamWritable
{
    t.Write(stream);
}
```

However, in the case of reading, you encounter a problem:

```
public interface IStreamReadable
{
    // When called, returns an instance 
    // deserialized from the stream.
    void Read(IStream stream);
}

...

T Read<T>(IStream stream) where T : IStreamReadable, new()
{
    var t = new T();
    t.Read(stream);
    return t;
}
```

This might appear to work, but it makes assumptions about how the object being deserialized is to be instantiated. Perhaps you want to return an existing instance instead of creating a new one? It also requires the `new()` constraint, which may be undesirable.

After all, when you are working outside the context of a specific instance, it makes sense to work in a static context instead. So you could try this:

```
public interface IStreamReadable
{
    // When called, returns an instance 
    // deserialized from the stream.
    static IStreamReadable Read(IStream stream);
}

...

T Read(IStream stream) where T : IStreamReadable
{
    return T.Read(stream);
}
```

Or, alternatively, to avoid boxing:

```
public interface IStreamReadable<T> where T : IStreamReadable<T>
{
    // When called, returns an instance 
    // deserialized from the stream.
    static T Read(IStream stream);
}

...

T Read(IStream stream) where T : IStreamReadable<T>
{
    return T.Read(stream);
}
```

Unfortunately, neither compiles, because you can't declare static members in interfaces. If the compiler would let me do this, however, it would be the ideal solution as it makes no assumptions about how you handle instantiation and instead defers that responsibility to the interface implementor.

I found a somewhat nice solution that works in the case of structs:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void Foo();
}

...

CallFoo<T>() where T : struct, IFoo
{
    return default(T).Foo();
}
```

Where the implementor of `IFoo` calls a static method. Of course, this approach will fail in the case of reference types due to `default(T)` returning `null` in this case. 
Using `return new T().Foo();` could also work, but this requires the `new()` constraint again, and discards the instance of `T`needlessly creating garbage.

I've considered using reflection somehow as a work around, but I was wondering if anyone has come up with their own work arounds to this limitation that they'd like to share.

Comment: The notion that a class should be responsible for serializing/deserializing instances of itself violates the Single Responsibility Principle. Why not separate the read/write methods into a separate class/interface?

Comment: While you may have a good point, it was meant as an example and not the specific issue at hand. Great topic for another discussion, for sure.

Comment: I'd guess that if this example illustrates the problem you're facing, then the same principle probably applies to your real-world problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem will be solved if you delegate the responsibility of creating IStreamReadable objects to a "Factory"class

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    public interface IStream { }
    public interface IStreamWritable { void Write(IStream stream); }
    public interface IStreamReadable { void Read(IStream stream); }
    public interface IStreamReadableFactory { IStreamReadable Create(); }

    public class InstanceFactory : IStreamReadableFactory
    {
        public IStreamReadable Create() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
    public class StaticFactory : IStreamReadableFactory
    {
        public static IStreamReadable GetInstance() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        IStreamReadable IStreamReadableFactory.Create() { return GetInstance(); }
    }

    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            IStream stream = null;
            var s1 = Read(new StaticFactory(), stream);
            var s2 = Read(new InstanceFactory(), stream);
        }

        static IStreamReadable Read(IStreamReadableFactory factory, IStream stream)
        {
            var t = factory.Create();
            t.Read(stream);
            return t;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose you are working in a generic context, but you want to be sure that instances of `T` are able to serialize themselves to a stream (could be a file, a list of bytes), and that instances of `T` can be deserialized from a stream.

I would personally not care whether instances of `T` can deserialize *themselves*, so much as that they *can be serialized* to/from a stream. The way to do that is not to force `T` to provide an implementation for those methods (since that class probably has other responsibilities), but rather to force somebody to provide an implementation that *can*.

Given the interface:

```
public interface IStreamDeserializer<T>
{
    T Read(IStream stream);
}
```

... you could write a method like this:

```
public T GetFromFile<T>(string path, IStreamDeserializer<T> deserializer)
{
    using (var stream = GetFileStream(path))
    {
        return deserializer.Read(stream);
    }
}
```

So in order to call `GetFromFile<Foo>(...)`, someone would have to produce a class that knows how to deserialize `Foo` objects. They'd be *injecting* that dependency into your method.

Of course, the existence of a Deserializer may not be a prerequisite of *every* implementation of `GetFromFile()`--this is an aspect of your implementation that may change for different reasons than your method signature. So you should probably use *constructor injection* instead, which would imply that your class becomes generic rather than just your method.

```
public class FileEntityRetriever<T> : IFileEntityRetriever
{
    IStreamDeserializer<T> deserializer;

    public FileEntityRetriever(IStreamDeserializer<T> deserializer)
    {
        this.deserializer = deserializer;
    }

    public T GetFromFile(string path, IStreamDeserializer<T> deserializer)
    {
        using (var stream = GetFileStream(path))
        {
            return deserializer.Read(stream);
        }
    }

}
```